# React: Make components external

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, components

I've been trying to get into React and therefore read the official guides, however, I'm not sure how to put components into their own files to reuse them across files.

I've made a very basic React Component which holds an `input` tag and some configuration with it. I would like to make this input tag a standalone component in its own file. How do I achieve this?

I use Webpack with this configuration:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  }
};
```

This is the React code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {text: ''};
  },
  handleChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value})
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>What's your name?</h1>
        <input 
            type="text" 
            value={this.state.text} 
            onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <h2>Hallo, {this.state.text}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Edit: I forgot the index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './Components/App';

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an app.js or something that binds to an element?

Comment: @erichardson30 Oh yes! Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to create an input component and pass your state and handle change function as props to the component.

Input Component :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

var Input = React.createClass({
  handleChange: function(e) {
    this.props.handleChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.props.text}
        onChange={this.handleChange} />
    )
  }
});
export default Input;
```

Your current component (with the input component added in):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from './path_to_inputComponent';

export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {text: ''};
  },
  handleChange: function(text) {
    this.setState({text: text})
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>What's your name?</h1>
        <Input text={this.state.text} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        <h2>Hallo, {this.state.text}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

So what will happen is, `this.state.text` will be passed as the text prop to Input which will set the value of the input. This will allow the input component to be used in multiple places and have a different `value` in each place that it is used. Also, when the `onChange` event is fired from the input, it will call the function that `handleChange` function that is passed to it as a prop. Therefore, it will call the function in the parent component and the state will be updated in the parent component.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but my entire component is already being shown with the `index.js`, similiarly to how you describe it. What I wanted to do is make the `input` tag its own component for the `App.js` to use

Comment: Okay, I did not understand what you were asking. I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: I noticed that instead of accessing the state in the input component, you just use the props passed to it since they change when the parent component gets rerendered when the state changes, right? Is that what you would always do in child components, use props and expect rerendering to give you other props after time?

Comment: Any child component should be "dumb" meaning that it should essentially only display information. It should not know about the state of the application or be able to change the state. The parent component should be the one to change and update the state. And when the state changes, it will re-render the component and the child component will therefore be re-rendered with the new state passed as props